# more on getSymbols downloading data for multiple symbols and calculate monthly returns

Tags: r, quantmod

Ref made to this post [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377590/getsymbols-downloading-data-for-multiple-symbols-and-calculate-returns)

I'm downloading a series of symbols and I need to calculate monthly returns for the adjusted close and I just can't seem to get it working. The earlier post I have ref to deal with the issue using ROC @Joshua Ulrich, but this is for daily returns. The other examples uses 'close', which is no good for me.

My starting point:

```
library('quantmod')
tickers <- c("XOM","MSFT","JNJ","GE","CVX","WFC","PG","JPM","VZ","PFE",
         "T","IBM","MRK","BAC","DIS","ORCL","PM","INTC","SLB")
#The following gives me what I need, but using Close instead of Adjusted
stocks_ret <- lapply(tickers, function(sym) monthlyReturn(type = 'log',(na.omit(getSymbols(sym, from='2013-01-01, auto.assign=FALSE)))))
```

Joshua Ulrich solution (works great, but I got no idea how to turn it into monthly returns):

```
# create environment to load data into
Data <- new.env()
getSymbols(c("^GSPC",Symbols), from="2007-01-01", env=Data)
# calculate returns, merge, and create data.frame (eapply loops over all
# objects in an environment, applies a function, and returns a list)
Returns <- eapply(Data, function(s) ROC(Ad(s), type="discrete"))
ReturnsDF <- as.data.frame(do.call(merge, Returns))
#adjust column names are re-order columns
colnames(ReturnsDF) <- gsub(".Adjusted","",colnames(ReturnsDF))
ReturnsDF <- ReturnsDF[,c("GSPC",Symbols)]
```

Then I tried:

```
Returns <- eapply(Data, function(s) ROC(Ad(s)[endpoints(tickers, on = 'months'),], type="discrete"))
```

The latter gives me an error message: " Error in try.xts(x, error = "must be either xts-coercible or timeBased")"

However, I cant find a solution to how I can calculate on MONTHLY basis instead og daily.. 'n=21' does not solve the issue..

Anyone??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris, this is one way for solving your question

```
library('quantmod')
library('dplyr')
tickers <- c("XOM","MSFT","JNJ","GE","CVX","WFC","PG","JPM","VZ","PFE",
             "T","IBM","MRK","BAC","DIS","ORCL","PM","INTC","SLB")

Stock_Data <- tickers %>% lapply(function(x) getSymbols(x,auto.assign=FALSE)) %>%
  lapply(function(x) monthlyReturn(Ad(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Any way of doing it without using yet another package?

Comment: Yes. Stock_Data <- lapply(tickers,function(x) getSymbols(x,auto.assign=FALSE))
Stock_Data_Final <- lapply(Stock_Data,function(x) monthlyReturn(Ad(x)))